# when does dispatch.xml get updated?

Tags: google-app-engine

I understand that the dispatch.xml that resides in the default service WEB-INF/ is the one that the appengine pays attention to.  However, when I do an appengine:update (java, mvn) the routing rules don't seem to update.  I actually have to do a separate appengine:update_dispatch to effect the changes.  Do I misunderstand something or am doing something incorrectly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's an understanding problem. You appear to be expecting a single operation. It's not.

Updating the default service app code and updating the dispatch rules (an app-level config affecting *all* app services) are distinct, independently executable operations, mapped as such in `mvn`.

From [Uploading the dispatch file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-routed#uploading_the_dispatch_file):

> To upload the dispatch file, use the [`appcfg update_dispatch`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/appcfg-arguments)
>   command, and specify the war directory for the default service. Be
>   sure that all the services mentioned in the file have already been
>   uploaded before using this command. # cd to the war directory
>   containing the default service appcfg.sh update_dispatch .
>
> You can also upload the dispatch file at the same time you upload one
>   or more services, by adding the optional `auto_update_dispatch` flag,
>   which can be used in two forms:
>
> ```
> appcfg.sh --auto_update_dispatch update <app-directory>|<files...>
> appcfg.sh -D update <app-directory>|<files...>
> ```

I guess it's possible to create a single mapping as well, under the hood using that `--auto_update_dispatch` flag, but IMHO it'd be even more confusing and you'd still need to remember 2 separate cmds (I wouldn't like to potentially affect other running services by a dispatch update when I'm uploading a particular service).